# Intermediate Value Theorem (Connectivity)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

I would appreciate any advice that nudges me in the right direction if the proof is wrong.
But please do NOT give any solution since this is an assignment question.

**Problem**:
Let f: X->R be a continuous function and X a connected topological space. Suppose a<b are real numbers with f(x)=a and f(y)=b, for some x,y in X. Prove that for any c in (a,b), there exists z in X with f(z)=c.

**Attempted Solution**:
Suppose otherwise, such that there exists c in (a,b) where for all x in X, $f(x){\neq}c$. Then, $f^{-1}((c,inf)){\cup}f^{-1}((-inf,c))=X$, and $f^{-1}((c,inf))$ & $f^{-1}((-inf,c))$ are open. Also, the intersection of these sets is an empty set. Since the above sets are clearly non-empty  (since f(x)=a and f(y)=b) and open, as well as disconnects X, this implies X is disconnected. But this is a contradiction since X is connected. Thus, for any c in (a,b), there exists z in X with f(z)=c.

****Please do NOT give a solution to this problem since it's an assignment problem.

Comment: This is fine: you’ve solved the problem. (To get $\infty$, use `\infty`.)

Comment: The typesetting (MathJax) could be improved, otherwise the answer is perfect.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you!

Comment: @MartinR Thank you!

Comment: @Pete: You’re welcome!